# Error inserting a timestamp with pg_query_params

Tags: php, postgresql-8.4

Im working in postgres 8.4 and PHP 5.4.3 using pg_query_params. I have a table called armies taht have 3 rows (well only for this example, it really have more). the id is an integer and the other two are timestamp withouth timezone. Now the SQL insert is:

INSERT INTO public.armies(id,build_start,build_end) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)

And the array I'm inserting is:

```
    $data['id'] = 1;
    $data['build_start'] = "now()";
    $data['build_end'] = "now() + time '00:00:50'";
```

The error is E_WARNING: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp:  «now() + time '00:00:50'»

Its works when i tried to insert it as a raw sql using pg_query like : INSERT INTO public.armies(id,build_start,build_end) VALUES (11935,now(),now() + time '00:00:50').

So I guess it has something to do with the pg_query_params(), I really really want to insert it using pg_query_params.

What I want to achieve is sum that now() with that 00:00:50 seconds, so i can manage to alter that $data['build_end'].

Answer (score 0):

Please do note that you are passing string literals

```
$data['build_start'] = "now()";
$data['build_end'] = "now() + time '00:00:50'";
```

to pg_query_params which cannot prepare a valid date/time value from "now()" or "now() + time '00:00:50'".

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO public.armies(id,build_start,build_end) VALUES ($1,$2,$3);
```

change it to

```
INSERT INTO public.armies(id,build_start) VALUES ($1,now());
```

and remove the parameters

```
$data['build_start'] = "now()";
$data['build_end'] = "now() + time '00:00:50'";
```

Now when the action completes, update the table.

```
UPDATE public.armies SET build_end=now() WHERE id=$1;
```

Hope I was able to help you.